# PHPscript time increasing in php

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to check dnd of numbers by using api. there are more than 5000 numbers in my database. i want check the dnd status of each number. i took help of external api. When i am running program its throwing 500 exception after 30 sec. i tried to improve it adding more time in php.ini but its not working and i have used set_time_limit(0) also. Its also not working. Can any one please suggest i am posting the code i used. i am using php 5.6

```
<?php
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
//ini_set('max_input_time', 3000);
set_time_limit(30000); 
require_once('config.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DND CHECK </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table align="center">
            <tr><td>Sno</td><td>Number</td><td>DND Check</td></tr>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM group_new";
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            $c=0;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $num = urlencode($row['number']);

                $json_string = 'http://dndchecker.railsroot.com/api?mobile_number='.$num;
                $ch = curl_init($json_string);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                $ex = json_decode($response); 
                $ex1 = $ex->status;
                // close the connection, release resources used
                curl_close($ch);
                $er = strcmp($ex1,"Never");

                echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['number']."</td><td>".$er."
            </tr>";

            $c=$c+1;
        }
        $db->close();
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of increasing the execution time blindly, can you check your error log ? or enable error reporting in your php page to check out the real issue ?

Comment: Thank you hassan there are no errors in my error lo i have checked it, its showing empty....

Comment: 500 exception means that there are an error [fatal, syntax ... etc]

Comment: however, often increasing the time limit needs to increasing the memory limit too, `ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXX');`

Comment: also increasing the time limit from php.ini under apache needs to restart your apache , make sure of that.

Comment: ya but my error log is empty and when i tried same script with 50 numbers its working

Comment: make sure that you had enabled the error logging from your apache2 server